# e(fx) clipse doesn't work on fresh macOS Mojave Java 11

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, macos-mojave, efxclipse

I just installed the newest Eclipse and e(fx)clipse, but it didn't change anything - I have no idea why javafx imports are not resolved.

Sorry I can't provide more proves I tried to solve it, but I just think (and remember it was I like that before) installing it and restarting Eclipse should be sufficient.

Comment: @Andreas I don't see this error anywhere. Even if the cause is the same, my question is different.

Comment: @Andreas another thing: the accepted answer there doesn't mention e(fx)clipse at all - and I suppose this is what it is for - so I don't need to care about the details of installation. I just checked what is in installed JREs and it seems ok (it's JDK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of [e(fx)clipse](https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) is not to resolve JavaFX imports. If using Java 11 or higher, you have to add the JavaFX dependency yourself because **JavaFX has been removed in Java 11**. See Java 11 release notes:

> JavaFX is no longer included in the JDK. It is now available as a
>   separate download from [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/).

See: [**Getting Started with JavaFX 11**](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx)

e(fx)clipse offers as a [runtime](https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html#about-runtime) e. g. a way to build JavaFX OSGi/Eclipse-based applications and provides [tooling](https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html#about-tooling) for JavaFX, e. g. to edit FXML files.